# Right coordinates for data defined position of diagrams

Tags: qgis, coordinates, position, diagram

I'm using QGIS 2.8.2 and want to define the position of diagrams with x and y coordinates.

The same thing works with the labels, but when I define coordinates for the diagrams they just disappear. 
I've tried different ways of coordinates but everytime they disappear. 
I think there is a problem with the Coordinate Reference System. I had to use WSG 84 EPSG:3857 and EPSG:4326 because otherwise my map is stretched.

I'm searching the web and the documentation for hours but i can't solve the problem, i am still a very beginner. Has anyone an idea to fix my problem?

Comment: Is it possible the coordinates for the diagrams are in *page* units? ArcPlot used to be like that, when working within the canvas with canvas objects (like text) coordinates are canvas coordinates (depending on your spatial reference) but diagrams are a page object, coordinates might be in pixels of your screen or inches on your page. Is this in print composer view?

Comment: You can check by going Project>Project Properties>General - then look down at the canvas units. If you are using WSG 84 EPSG:3857 and EPSG:4326 the your units will most likely be in decimal degrees.

Answer (score 2):

The coordinates must be in the same crs as the layer the diagrams are attached to. Could this be your issue?